# Errors using TPU on Google Colab for training a simple DQN agent to solve cartpole environment

Tags: tf.keras, tpu, dqn

I am trying to learn reinforcemnt learning and started exploring a few examples.
I was able to train the DQN model to solve the cartpole environment using the GPU (Both on my local machine and using colab GPU (T4) ).The time taken per episode is almost same on both. I was wondering, If I run the same model on a TPU, will it execute faster.

Here is the colab notebook, ([https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I1KdH9HD2F_G5-vpCSB2jSN8qQtCuKcB#scrollTo=kZ7ve1ihiLN7](https://stackoverflow.com))

(Note that: I made the necessary changes to take TPU in runtime, and also added a block of code for resolver and TPU strategy.)

The problem is
Whenever the code enters into predict method (either during action or in the retrain method), It gives the following error.

[InvalidArgumentError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyiCd.png)

Also, I went through the following example.
[https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/classification_iris_data_with_keras.ipynb#scrollTo=ZhnrwcSe3KER&uniqifier=1](https://stackoverflow.com)

In the above example, they use a sequential model similar to the one I'm trying to evaluate.

I couldn't find any differences in the model as such. However, the first code doesn't work while the second one works.

Can someone please let me know if there is any step I'm missing out?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a TensorFlow operation which is not supported by TPU.  It is important to notice that not all TensorFlow ops are supported by TPU - you can check for support at [at this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops).

If you are interested in creating a custom operation to your training, it is possible but require some steps to be taken, but it is not much trivial. Normally it is better to find alternative TF ops (supported by TPU) to replace the unsupported ones.